# One who loves science

Tags: meaning, neologisms

Would I be off base if I suggested (or created) the word "sciophile"? Meaning "one who loves science".

Comment: Oops, LOL. Misspelled wonderful.

Comment: You can always edit your question. No need to mention the changes in comments.

Comment: Did you try Googling [the word](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=s45BVoWaOIrN8gf1lpygCA#q=%22sciophile%22&start=20)?

Comment: *Wounderful* is accurate.

Comment: If anything, *scioplile* would mean love of shadows, given that [*sciophobia*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sciophobia) means fear of shadows and [*sciophyte*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sciophyte) is a plant that grow best in the shade.

Answer (score -1):

Who would catch you off base?

There's the word [*sciolist*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sciolist%20definition), which means someone with superficial knowledge, so by analogy your coinage might be taken to mean love of knowledge.

Consider the word [*scientism*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=scientism%20definition), which refers to science, which is to say the investigation of the natural world by natural means -- physics, chemistry, biology, etc.  So by analogy, perhaps a better choice would be *scientiphilia*.

Comment: Maybe someone didn't like the proposed word *scientiphilia*? It looks like a neologism. Do you have a citation showing people have actually used it as a word? Also, I'm not sure what the relevance of *sciolist* is–it does show the same root *sci-* found in *science,* but the *o* is part of the diminutive suffix *-ol-*, so it's not an example of *scio-* being used as a combining form meaning "science." (Oh, I just noticed one more thing–the original post is technically asking for a word for a person, so you may want to edit your suggestion to *scientiphile.*)

Comment: See the OP: "suggested (or *created*)", so a neologism is not out of place. The relevance of *sciolist* is that the *sci* refers to knowledge, not science, so by analogy *sciophile* wouldn't be the best choice for the OP's needs.  I don't mind that someone thinks *scientiphilia* is a bad choice.  I object to the refusal to post a correction to my reasoning or at least an argument against.  Point taken for *scientiphile*.